# How to read XML string from DB into XMLTextReader?

Tags: c#, xml, xmldocument, xmlreader, xmltextreader

Ihave an issue with reading an XML string into XMLTextReader..

I'm querying the a DB and getting a DataSet back.
From that DataSet, I'm reading a specific row and column (which contains XML strings) and using that XML string value to pass to an XMLTextReader.
The problem is that I'm getting the error "Illegal Character in path".

I know that the XML string returned from the DB is proper, as I can open the XML in my browser.

This is the code I'm using:

```
string XMLstring = DS.Tables[0].Rows[i][y].ToString();
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.LoadXml(XMLstring);

StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
XmlTextWriter xw = new XmlTextWriter(sw);
xmlDoc.WriteTo(xw);
XmlTextReader textReader = new XmlTextReader(sw.ToString());
```

Any ideas why I'm getting this error??

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [XMLTextReader constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1af7xa52.aspx) overloads. You're trying to load an XML string, and the String overload expects a path.

Try writing the XML string out to a file, and give the XMLTextReader that file's path.

Comment: You are right.. but it seems redundant to write the XML string to a file 1st everytime..
I even tried to read the string into a MemoryStream, and pass that to the XMLTextReader as a parameter, but that also did not work.

Comment: Maybe you're going about the problem strangely. What are you trying to accomplish? The XmlDocument class provides (pretty) good DOM support and manipulation.

Comment: I agree with dominus, if you've got the data in the XmlDocument, why bother putting in an XmlTextReader?